# Having trouble figuring out how to call form's procedure from a DLL

Tags: vb.net

The project uses a DLL to provide an interface to a common program that communicates via named pipes. When data is received on the DLL's pipes thread I need to call a procedure that resides on a Form in the application. I've tried all sorts of things but nothing seems to work. 
The form's Sub cannot be reached. I assume I need to use a delegate but the DLL has no forms and I can't figure out how to use a delegate in this situation.

Code excerpts below:

```
Public Sub Receive()
    'This is the Client's receiver for the client's request return
    'The Client's pipe name is passed to the local UDPserver in the request
    'This routine is on a seperate thread and is started prior to any 
    'communications to the local UDPserver 

    Dim RequestBytes(ByteSize) As Byte
    Dim RequestByteCount As Integer = 0
    Try
        doNotify = New NotifyDelegate(AddressOf NotifyClient)
        ClientReceive = New NamedPipeServerStream(ClientPipeName, PipeDirection.In, 1, PipeTransmissionMode.Message, PipeOptions.Asynchronous)

        ClientReceiveActive = True
        While EndOfService = False
            ClientReceive.WaitForConnection()
            RequestByteCount = ClientReceive.Read(RequestBytes, 0, ByteSize)
            'Strip the CrLf (13, 10) indicating end of bytes
            Array.Resize(RequestBytes, RequestByteCount - 2)
            If RequestByteCount > 0 Then
                'Convert bytes back to string
                ServerReturn = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(RequestBytes)
            End If
            Array.Resize(RequestBytes, ByteSize)

            If ServerReturn.ToUpper.IndexOf("!") <> -1 Then
                'A broadcast Notification 
                Owner.Invoke(doNotify, New Object() {ServerReturn})
                ServerReturnValid = False
            Else
                'Send_Request that the server has returned
                ServerReturnValid = True
            End If
            ClientReceive.Disconnect()
        End While
    Catch ex As ThreadAbortException
        'Prevent error message for thread abort
        Thread.ResetAbort()
        ClientReceive.Close()
        Err.Clear()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "ClientPipe Receive")
        Err.Clear()
    End Try

    ClientReceiveActive = False
End Sub

Public Sub NotifyClient(ByVal Notification As String)
    'Server generated notifications are sent here via delegate doNotify
    Notification = Notification.Replace("!", String.Empty)
End Sub
```

The line `Owner.Invoke(doNotify, New Object() {ServerReturn})` works because I have a dummy form in the DLL that allows the invoke and it calls `NotifyClient` in the DLL.

This works but I want the `NotifyClient` Sub to be on the applications form that is identified when the DLL is instantiated and not declared in the DLL.

Comment: The `Receive` method doesn't seem to have anything to do with any form logic at all... So it would be even better to move the `Receive` method to a separate dedicated class or module, remove the `MsgBox` call in the exception handling logic (and use a return value instead so the caller can handle showing a message) and inject the `NotifyClient` delegate (either as a method parameter or as a property of that new class). Separation of concerns.

Comment: I may not have described the problem correctly. The Receive Sub is in the DLL class Library. The thread is also started by a DLL Function. When the Recieve thread recieves a response I want to call a Sub method residing on a form in the application that uses the DLL. The specific form is the one that instiantated the DLL. All my research to date since the post says I can't do it. My original thought was to pass the application's form as 'Me' to the DLL. Then call the form's method as: form.methodname(notification) but the compiler doesn't like it. It has no idea who or what 'Me' is.

Answer (score 0):

Since your `Sub` inside the `Form` isn't static you need an actual `Form` object to be able to call the `Sub`.

```
Dim frm As <FormClassName>
frm = New <FormClassName>
...
frm.Receive
```

If the `Sub` inside the `Form` doesn't use any of the local variables or functions of the `Form` you could declare the `Sub` static, then you can call it without having an actual `Form` object.

```
Public Shared Sub Receive
    ...
End Sub
```

You can call it like this without an actual object.

```
<FormClassName>.Receive
```

Comment: Declaring a form instance just to call the `Receive` method seems quite ugly to me. Making the `Receive` method shared would be a pretty straightforward solution, because the logic that the `Receive` method contains does not relate to form instances anyway. (Because it does not relate to any form logic at all, moving the `Receive` method to a separate class altogether would be even better imho.)

Comment: Bart The DLL needs to be usable by many applications. All have a Notify method to update data. I'm trying to call that method from the Recieve sub of the DLL. As i commented above my research says I can't do it. because the compiler has know way of knowing the form or its method I want to call. The best I have bee anle to do by passing the form to the DLL is set the forms Tag property. None of the controls or methods can be seen on the form at compue time only the forms inherited stuff.

Comment: Thanks for your help but I decided to add a couple of properties to the DLL that the instantating form can poll before displaying any data affected by the notification.  However, if anyone knows how to do this type of callback I am all ears.